# Moment generating function of a cumulative discrete distribution

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have the following cumulative distribution function:

```
    F(x) = 0, if x < 0
        2/8, if 0 <= x < 2
        3/8, if 2 <= x < 4
        1, if >= 4
```

I have been asked to find the moment generating of function and I am not sure how to do that. Would really appreciate any help!

Note '<=' refers to less than equal to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is the distribution function of the random variable such that $P(X = 0) = 1/4$, $P(X=2) = 1/8$, $P(X = 4) = 5/8$.
Hence, for every $s \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ E[\exp(sX)] = \frac{2+\exp(s) + 5\exp(2s)}{8}. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got a similar answer but was confused.
If you don't mind, could you explain how I could justify finding the probabilities?

Comment: Let $X$ be the random variable mentioned above. Let $F_X (x) := P(X \le x)$. Then, $F_X$ satisfies the conditions you mentioned. Conversely, if $F$ is a distribution function, then, there exists a unique probability measure on $\mathbb R$ such that $\mu( (a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$  for every $a < b$.  In this case $\mu$ is a discrete distribution.

Comment: That makes a lot sense, thanks a lot again!